# Can anyone determine what kind of encryption this is?

Tags: encryption

Here are some examples of the encryption:

J01A062YLMP1
J01A06OEPMP1
J08A07GSVMP1
J08A0625YMP1
K01A06IE2MP1
K01A06GRKMP1
W08A06ZTYMP1

I know the first letter corresponds to a brand, the last 3 characters never change MP1, and there is always an A as the 4th character. Any suggestions on what type of encryption this is?

Comment: This might be marked as too localized, but do you have any other information? They just look like random uids matching the format `w0dA0dwwwMP1`

Comment: This doesn't look like encryption at all. It may be some sort of encoding, and really looks like more of a labeling/naming convention than anything else, but it's almost definitely *not* anything to do with cryptography whatsoever.

Answer (score 8):

Judging by the structured format, I would say this is not **encryption** of any kind, but **encoding**. A possible scheme could be as follows;

```
brand | year | divider | month | id   | postfix
------|------|---------|-------|------|--------
J     | 01   | A       | 06    | 2YL  | MP1
J     | 01   | A       | 06    | OEP  | MP1
J     | 08   | A       | 07    | GSV  | MP1
J     | 08   | A       | 06    | 25Y  | MP1
K     | 01   | A       | 06    | IE2  | MP1
K     | 01   | A       | 06    | GRK  | MP1
W     | 08   | A       | 06    | ZTY  | MP1
```

The problem with encoding is you need a lookup table to figure out what any of it means. I would guess that these are keys to a database, and without that database you have no way of knowing what records these keys map to.

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like you are right lynks. I will try this again and see if I can determine more of what the encoding should be. I appreciate your help! :)